# How remove/hide an action field link?

Tags: 8

On a node field form (admin/structure/types/manage/article/fields), I have a dropdown with action links for all fields.

- Edit
- Storage Settings
- Delete

I would like know if it's possible to unset the "Delete" link for a field please.
I have try with hook_link_alter() but I don't know how find and remove the link for a specific field (by example field_image).

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming those operations check access correctly (not doing so would be a bug), you can use `hook_ENTITY_TYPE_access`, e.g. in your case `hook_field_config_access`, there you can deny delete access for a field with a given name.

Answer (score 0):

to find the location of the field you want to unset, use the Devel Module:

> Helper functions for Drupal developers and inquisitive admins. This
>   module can print a summary of all database queries for each page
>   request at the bottom of each page. The summary includes how many
>   times each query was executed on a page (shouldn't run same query
>   multiple times), and how long each query took (short is good - use
>   cache for complex queries). Also a dprint_r($array) function is
>   provided, which pretty prints arrays. Useful during development.
>   Similarly, a ddebug_backtrace() is offerred. much more. See this
>   helpful demo page.

then you could use hook_form_alter() to actually unset the value.  to get the form information, something like:

```
hook_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id)
{
  dpm($form); // from devel module

  if($form_id == FORM_ID_THAT_HOLDS_ELEMENT_TO_HIDE)
  {
    unset($form[field]...);
  }
}
```

dpm will show the structure of any array, including the form - you can drill down into the data to find the exact location of the item you want to unset

Answer (score 0):

The page you are seeing is an admin form, by default Drupal has not created permissions for the action buttons/ Actions on this form.